# Numpy add given rows

Tags: python, numpy

Given a numpy array for example

```
A = np.ones(shape=(7, 6), dtype=np.float32)
```

and a list

```
v = [[0, 2], [1, 4], [3, 5, 6]]
```

what I want to do is adding rows in `A` given each item in `v`, for `v`, there are 3 items, for `v[0]`, add row `0` and row `2` column-wisely. The shape of the output is `(3, 6)` and the output is

```
res = array([[2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
             [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
             [3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.]])

# res[0] = A[0] + A[2]
# res[1] = A[1] + A[4]
# res[2] = A[3] + A[5] + A[6]
```

Here is a more clear example, give a matrix

```
m = [[1, 2, 3],
      [2, 3, 4],
      [1, 1, 1],
      [2, 2, 2],
      [1, 1, 1]]
```

and rows to be added

```
 v = [[0, 1, 3], [2]]
```

so, here add rows `0`, `1`, and `3` in matrix `m` and since there is only one row to be added in `[2]`, so the result is

```
# res.shape = (2, 3)
res[0] = m[0] + m[1] + m[3]
res[1] = m[2]
```

Are there any more elegant way to do so?

Comment: not clear. please edit and add a minimal example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use fancy indexing to select rows from your array.

For `A`:

```
>>> A = np.ones(shape=(7, 6), dtype=np.float32)
>>> v = [[0, 2], [1, 4], [3, 5, 6]]
>>> np.array([A[rows].sum(axis=0) for rows in v])
array([[2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.]], dtype=float32)
```

For `m`:

```
>>> m = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1]])
>>> v = [[0, 1, 3], [2]]
>>> np.array([m[rows].sum(axis=0) for rows in v])
array([[5, 7, 9],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```

I don't know if this can be vectorized further.